# Can't install my pip package due to pre-existing build directory

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

I get the following error when I've uninstalled and then try to re-install the pip package I'm working on.

pip can't proceed with requirement `my-package` due to a pre-existing build directory.
 `location: /private/var/folders/t0/45yvxfds0gsgyvd3147j2sk00000gp/T/pip_build_jonathan/my-package`. This is likely due to a previous installation that failed.
pip is being responsible and not assuming it can delete this.
Please delete it and try again.

But the previous installation didn't fail. So I'm wondering if you have to do something to clean up the build directory in your code when you install a package. What do you have to do in that case?

**Update**

```
Downloading/unpacking my-package
  Downloading my-package-0.16.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/t0/45yvxfds0gsgyvd3147j2sk00000gp/T/pip_build_jonathan/my-package/setup.py) egg_info for package my-package

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): docopt in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from my-package)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from my-package)
```

I noticed that it's running setup.py like this when you're installing my package. Whereas when you install other packages it only says that it was successfully installed. No mention of setup.py.

```
import os
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from pip.req import parse_requirements

CONFIG_PATH = '~/'

install_reqs = parse_requirements('requirements.txt')
reqs = [str(ir.req) for ir in install_reqs]
setup(name='my-package',
      packages=['my-package'],
      version='0.17',
      description='description',
      author='My name',
      author_email='email@email.com',
      keywords=['some keywodrd'],
      url='',
      scripts=['scriptfile'],
      install_requires=reqs,
      data_files=[(os.path.expanduser(CONFIG_PATH), ['.config.json'])]
```

Comment: I guess you may just have to delete it manually.  If the problem is repeatable, then let us know.

Comment: Show us the contents of your `setup.py`.